# Bookshelf.js unique email validation before create new record

Tags: node.js, validation, express, bookshelf.js, joi

Am trying to validate Email already exists validation in [Bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/) when creating new record.

I found one solution here [github](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/812) but its not working, even i tried with [Promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('saving', this._assertEmailUnique);
  },
  _assertEmailUnique: function(model, attributes, options) {
    if (this.hasChanged('email')) {
      return this
        .query('where', 'email', this.get('email'))
        .fetch(_.pick(options, 'transacting'))
        .then(function (existing) {
          if (!existing) throw new Error('duplicate email');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

For Model validation currently am using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi), looks like Joi also not supporting for custom validation for this. Am using Postgres Database. There is any other way to do it.. Please help...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has **two** errors preventing it to work:

1. the `if (!existing) ...` should be inverted, because you want to fail if the given email already exists
2. querying on `this` will constrain your query to the current record, you need to query from scratch, using plain `User`

With those fixes your code will look like:

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('saving', this._assertEmailUnique);
  },
  _assertEmailUnique: function(model, attributes, options) {
    if (this.hasChanged('email')) {
      return User
        .query('where', 'email', this.get('email'))
        .fetch(_.pick(options || {}, 'transacting'))
        .then(function(existing) {
          if (existing) {
            throw new Error('Duplicated email: User id #' + existing.id);
          }
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked, one thing i have removed this ``_.pick(options || {}, 'transacting')``  from ```fetch()``` method, then only query executing.. Otherwise fine

Comment: @flaviodesousa I'm using bookshelf with hapi-bookshelf-models plugins. I am not able to access the Model inside the _assertEmailUnique method as you have mentioned. I'm just getting an error `"User.query is not a function"`. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

it is **MORE EFFICIENT** to set a unique key constraint on the `email` column and then within the model, catch when it becomes violated.

e.g 
in your database migration side do something like

```
...
table.string('email').notNullable().unique();
```

then override the `save` method of the model and throw application specific error from there like so:

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  save: function () {
        return bookshelf.Model.prototype.save.apply(this, arguments)
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.code === '23505') { //unique_violation code if using postgres db
                throw new errors.DuplicateUserEmail('User with the same email already exists');
            }

            throw error;
        });
    }
});
```